# Jodatime beforeOrEqual and afterOrEqual

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm using jodatime (java 6) to check dates in an interval, and i really need to do it more efficiently. Is there any way to avoid this mess : (all the variables are of type `org.joda.time.LocalDate`)

```
    if ((startReservation.isBefore(beginInterval) || startReservation.equals(beginInterval))
            && ((endReservation.isAfter(beginInterval) && (endReservation.isBefore(finishInterval) || endReservation.equals(finishInterval))))) {

            startReservation= beginInterval;
            //do stuff
    }
```

And a bunch of other `else if`s.

Does jodatime implement `beforeOrEqual()`/`afterOrEqual()` methods or similar ?

Comment: Can you please tell us explicitly what is the type of your variables like `startReservation`, `beginInterval` etc.? I first assumed `Interval` but after having looked at your logic I am not so sure any longer.

Comment: Sorry. It's `LocalDate` for all the variables.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your variables are objects of type `ReadableInstant`, the expression

`startReservation.isBefore(beginInterval) || startReservation.equals(beginInterval)`

is equivalent to the simpler and shorter expression:

`!startReservation.isAfter(beginInterval)`

**Important:** Using the method `equals()` might be harmful if your instants (notably `DateTime`) use different timezones. The proposed workaround is safer.

Joda-Time does not implement methods like `beforeOrEqual()` etc. but the workaround is so simple that the Joda-Time-Team has not considered this enhancement. **So you can finally do:**

```
if (
  !startReservation.isAfter(beginInterval) 
  && ((endReservation.isAfter(beginInterval) 
  && (!endReservation.isAfter(finishInterval)
) {
  startReservation= beginInterval;
  //do stuff
}
```

Side remark: Mathematically this is like a combination of Allen interval relations "starts", "finishedBy", "overlaps" and "equals" (equivalent).

Comment: I thought about this solution, but i figured it's maybe more readable to use a bunch of `if`s instead of a block of `else if`s
But since i'm using jodatime's `LocalDate` for my variables, should i be careful while using `equals()` ?

Comment: @user3557384 As long as all your `LocalDate`-objects use the same chronology (preferred ISO and not "coptic" or "GJ" or similar) then no problem with using `equals()` (or better `isEqual()`). By the way, do you nevertheless prefer methods like `beforeOrEqual()` etc. for readability even if the suggested workaround is so simple? Am just curious although there is no hope that Joda-Time will ever realize such methods since it is officially in maintenance mode. Also no hope that Joda-Time will ever realize date intervals (ranges).